# Hibernate LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session

Tags: java, hibernate

I have structure like this mapped in Hibernate (using XDoclet because it is old project):

```
public class Student {
     String name;
     int age;
     School school;    //many to one
     // ...
}

public class School {
     String name;
     // ...
}
```

I would like to print student's school name (using student object), like this:

```
System.out.println("School name: " + student.getSchool().getName());
```

but I am getting:

> org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy
>   - no Session

I wouldn't like to change mappings files (because I am not author of this), so what is other solution of this problem?

Comment: Post the content of the hbm files. It doesn't look like school is being initialized with the strdent

Comment: I only wanted to show relation many to one (student and school) in above sheet and error which I got. I don't want edit any hbm files, xdoclet codes etc. Is any other idea to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

How did you read Student object? 
Because if you are reading a `Student` from a method that close the session before returning, accessing a `@Lazy` collection will generate a `LazyInitializationException`.
I suggest you to check your session lifecycle.

Answer (score 0):

make sure your code calls the accessor methods of student before the session is closed. or in the case you are using spring and transactions, then it has to be under the scope where your session is active.